# Hole 196 и KRACK

Tags: безопасность, wifi, уязвимости

Возможно, вопрос глупый, но ответ узнать желаю.

Не так давно (в октябре этого года) обнаружили уязвимость KRACK в WPA2. Не переоткрытие ли это уязвимости Hole 196 (которую обнаружили в 2010 году)?

Comment: Нет, потому что это разное. Беглое чтение описаний Hole 196 и KRACK ясно дает это понять.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, спасибо!